# Ejb lookup failing on WAS7.0 with NamingException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, ejb-2.x

I have an application developed on RAD using WAS 6.0. I migrated the code to WID 7.0. After making some changes in the EJB modules(Had to remove the bnd.xmi file from each ejb module to deploy the application on Application Server)the application is running fine, but the EJB modules give the following error:

NamingException has Occured While Getting Local Home
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:nullName ejb/com/igcc not found in context "local:".

I am not able to figure out what changes do it need to make to run the application on WID.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Ayush

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "bnd.xmi" files you deleted are the WebSphere-specific deployment descriptors, containing binding information. One of the things that are mentioned there is the name under which to bind each individual EJB home.

You cannot possibly run an EJB module without this binding information existing *somewhere*.

If you delete these files (which are generated by RAD), you have to assign new binding information from within the administration console, or via your wsadmin-based deployment scripts.

In short... lets start by recovering those files that you erased. :-)